# Loop through element and change based on link attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Trying to figure this out. I am inexperienced at jQuery, and not understanding how to loop through elements and match one.

I have 3 divs:

```
    <div class="first-image">
      <img src="images/first.png">
    </div>
    <div class="second-image">
      <img src="images/second.png">
    </div>
    <div class="third-image">
      <img src="images/third.png">
    </div>
```

And off to the side, links in a div named 'copy' with rel = first-image, etc.:

```
<a href="#" onclick="return false" rel="first-image">...</a>
```

Clicking the link will fade up the image in the associated div (using GSAP TweenMax)
Here is the function I've been working on to do this... but I am not fully understanding how to loop through all the "rel" elements, and make a match to the one that has been clicked on.

```
<script>
//pause slideshow on members to ledger when text is clicked, and show associated image
$(function() {
 $('.copy').on('click','a',function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var slideName = $(this).attr('rel');

  $("rel").each(function(i){
    if (this.rel == slideName) {
      console.log(this);
    }
  });


    //var change_screens_tween = TweenMax.to('.'+slideName+'', 1, {
    //autoAlpha:1
    //});
    });
  });
</script>
```

What am I doing wrong? I don't even get an error in my browser. :-(

---

Thanks to the answer below, I got farther. Here is my revised code.

```
   $('[rel]').each(function(k, v){
    if (v == slideName) {
        var change_screens_tween = TweenMax.to('.'+slideName+'', 1, {
          autoAlpha:1
        });
    } else {
        var change_screens_tween = TweenMax.to('.'+slideName+'', 1, {
          autoAlpha:0
        });
    }
  });      
});
```

This is starting to work, but makes the screenshots appear and then instantly fade out. And it only works once. Any thoughts?

Comment: Use `v`, not `slideName`, when forming the class selector. You have three potential values; one of them will match `slideName`, two of them won't. If it doesn't match, you want to hide the one that doesn't match (so `v`), not the one you actually want to show (`slideName`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add brackets around rel, like so:

```
$('[rel]').each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('rel') == slideName) {
      console.log(this);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks @ateich! Is there a way to put all the "rel" values in an array in order to set CSS properties on the one that hasn't been matched? I can figure out a less elegant solution but your answer has helped.